# Clear jquery.validate error messages on change/hide of disabled attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

Trying to clear the error messages when the disabled fields are toggled on and off on my form using jquery.validate. Right now I have it working where on change or on click fields are showing and changing the prop from disabled. So it works for what I need which is hiding the fields that are not necessary and not validating them when they are in a disabled state. However, when I toggle these fields back to their disabled state ad hide them, the error messages are still showing until I click submit again. I tried adding the .valid() call to the toggleDisabled function and it does not make the messages disappear when they go back to a hidden/disabled state. Anyone see what can be added to make the messages disappear when the fields do?

Here is the working fiddle with what I have so far:
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dn8JX/2/)

And I am using jquery.validate from :

[jQuery.Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

HTML:

```
<form id="myform">
<input type="text" name="field1" />
<br/>
<br />
<input type="text" id="toggleInput" name="toggleInputName" disabled style="display:none" />
<input type="button" id="toggleButton" value="Toggle Disabled" />

<div id="tickets">
    <label for="group1">Number of Tickets: <span class="req">*</span></label>
    <select class="group1_dropdown" id="group1" name="group1">
        <option value="0">-- Please select --</option>
        <option value="1">Member</option>
        <option value="2">Member + 1 Guest</option>
        <option value="3">Member + 2 Guests</option>
        <option value="4">Member + 3 Guests</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input type="text" id="payMethod" name="payMethodName" disabled style="display:none" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myform').validate({
        onblur: true,
        onkeyup: false,
        ignore: ":disabled",
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            payMethodName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            toggleInputName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
//used for toggling/showing disabled fields - will display and make not disabled on same click event
(function ($) {
    $.fn.toggleDisabled = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.prop('disabled')) {
                $this.prop('disabled', false).show();
            } else {
                $this.prop('disabled', true).hide();
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
  $(function () {
    $('#toggleButton').click(function () {
        $('#toggleInput').toggleDisabled();
    });
});
$(function () {
$("#group1").change(function () {
    var str = "";
    str = parseInt($(this).val());
    if(str == 2)
        $("#payMethod").toggleDisabled();
    else
        $("#payMethod").toggleDisabled();
});

});
```

Comment: **FYI- there is no such jQuery Validate option called `onblur`.**  For this plugin, the option  is called `onfocusout` and you **must never set it to `true`**.  It's already the default behavior so just leave it out... I've seen setting it to `true` break the plugin.  See the documentation:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

Comment: Yeah I forgot about that using  onkeyup: false defaults it to the blur but you do not have to specify that. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Yes, but `onfocusout` is the _default_ behavior regardless of how you set `onkeyup`.   The two are not interlocked.   It's all spelled out in the docs.

Comment: Oh hey @Sparky, so I reviewed the docs again. Here ya go:  var v = $("#cmaForm").validate({
  errorClass: "warning",
  onkeyup: false,
  onblur: false,
  submitHandler: function() {
   alert("Submitted, thanks!");
  }
 });

Looks like the onblur is used. 

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/multipart/

Comment: That's an error in the docs.  [Look at the source code of the plugin itself](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js).  **There is no `onblur` option**.

Comment: It's not in the docs, that's directly from one of the sample forms.

Comment: You said that you _"reviewed the docs"_ and I simply responded.  Regardless, wherever you got that from is clearly mistaken as `onblur` is not part of the plugin source code.

Comment: And I appreciate your help on the matter. But that is from Jörn Zaefferer's site... i.e. It's his plugin. Did you look at the site?

Comment: Yes.  I'm very familiar with the site and it contains a few small mistakes.  Did you look at [the code in the plugin](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js)?   There is no `onblur` option defined in the plugin code, anywhere, period.  It will only take you a few seconds to open it up and do a text search.  http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js

Comment: Yes:  // http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/equalTo
  equalTo: function( value, element, param ) {
   // bind to the blur event of the target in order to revalidate whenever the target field is updated
   // TODO find a way to bind the event just once, avoiding the unbind-rebind overhead
   var target = $(param);
   if ( this.settings.onfocusout ) {
    target.unbind(".validate-equalTo").bind("blur.validate-equalTo", function() {
     $(element).valid();
    });
   }
   return value === target.val();
  },

Comment: Um, no, sorry... there is no `onblur` in the source code of the plugin.  You've only found a JS `blur` event inside the `equalTo` method.  Not even close.

Comment: Compare [jsFiddle `onfocusout:false`](http://jsfiddle.net/J4B2c/) to [jsFiddle `onblur:false`](http://jsfiddle.net/J4B2c/1/).  The second one simply ignores the imaginary `onblur` option.

Comment: I've also reported the bad code in the demo to Jörn at GitHub:  https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/1025

Comment: Well alrighty then. That should remedy the problem. Thanks. I'll have another question for you regarding a multi-page form that may or may not require the second page depending on a drop down and slideToggles the next group of inputs if you're around Sunday. Haven't tried to tackle that one but it is not a standard multi-page form because it will only be a second page if the user actually activates it with a dropdown (select). I'll ping ya when I try and tackle that. Thanks for clearing up the confusion about the onblur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have changed your plugin a little to do what you want.

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/aPR7L/)</kbd>

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.toggleDisabled = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                id = $this.attr('id'), //get the id of input
                label = $this.next('label[for="' + id + '"]'); //find the next label which is added by jQuery Validator
            if ($this.prop('disabled')) {
                label.show(); //show the label
                $this.prop('disabled', false).show();
            } else {
                label.hide();//hide the label
                $this.prop('disabled', true).hide();
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

---

Update

Another way without changing your plugin

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/aPR7L/3)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function () { //place your all DOM ready code in one DOM ready handler
    var validator = $('#myform').validate({ //assign validate to a variable
        //validator code here 
    });
    $('#toggleButton').click(function () {
        validator.resetForm();//reset Form validation
        $('#toggleInput').toggleDisabled();
    });
});
```

Comment: @isaacweathers Welcome Happy to help 
:)

Comment: Thanks again for the other method. That seems to work as well. I had not tried that because I did not want the entire form reset but it looks like just binding the resetForm to that particular function event only affects the input for that particular event and not all. Nice solution. Thanks.